# P.adjust - different values when using a list vs. individual p-values

Tags: p-value, post-hoc, false-discovery-rate

I am having some trouble determining the cause of an issue in my R coding. I have a series of 11 p-values, which correcting using the p.adjust function in R with BH corrections. When I create a list using the p-values and then use that list in the p.adjust function, I get different adjusted p-values then when I simply run each p-value in the p.adjust function independently. Can anyone help to explain why this might be the case and which way is giving the correct adjusted p-values? My code is below with the outputs. Thank you.

> #### Make a list of all p-values and use p.adjust to correct all p-values at once

> `pval_L_Sp19<-c(0.9103,0.7876,0.7499,0.7945,0.01989,0.03449,0.9882,0.8967,0.7919)`
> `p.adjust(pval_L_Sp19, method = "BH", n=9)`

[1] 0.988200 0.988200 0.988200 0.988200 0.155205 0.155205 0.988200 0.988200 0.988200

> #### Separating out each p-value and adjusting them individually while still using n=9
>
> `p.adjust(0.9103,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 1

> `p.adjust(0.7876,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 1

> `p.adjust(0.7499,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 1

> `p.adjust(0.7945,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 1

> `p.adjust(0.01989,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 0.17901

> `p.adjust(0.03449,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 0.31041

> `p.adjust(0.9882,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 1

> `p.adjust(0.8967,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 1

> `p.adjust(0.7919,method = "BH",n=9)`

[1] 1

Comment: Although this reads very much like a programming problem--and partly it is--it is grounded in a misunderstanding of what p-value adjustment does, so I would encourage people not to close it (and consider answering!).

Answer (score 3):

The R code for the BH method is quite simple and it should reveal why you get different results depending on whether you use the full vector or one value at a time.

For convenience, I start with a vector of p-values **sorted by decreasing order** (if they are not sorted this way, you would need some code to store the original order, sort, adjust, re-sort back to original; but that's just some list manipulations):

```
p <- c(0.9882, 0.9103, 0.8967, 0.7945, 0.7919, 0.7876, 0.7499, 0.03449, 0.01989)
i <- length(p):1
n <- length(p)
padj <- cummin(n/i * p)
padj <- ifelse(padj > 1, 1, padj) # Reset values that may have gone above 1
padj
[1] 0.988 0.988 0.988 0.988 0.988 0.988 0.988 0.155 0.155
```

The line `cummin(n/i * p)` keeps the running minimum of the vector `n/i * p` with `n` being the number of p-values and `i` a running index. This should explain why using a single p-value and a preset value of n gives a different result:

```
n <- 9
p <- 0.03449
i <- length(p):1           # Not very meanignful as  `i = 1`
padj <- cummin(n/i * p)    # This is just `n * p` 
padj <- ifelse(padj > 1, 1, padj)
padj
[1] 0.31
```

(Hope I got things right)

I think the intuition is that the BH method considers the distribution of pvalues not just the values individually and it adjusts them accordingly.

Comment: BH method depends on other observed p-values. If you don't tell it what the other p-values are, it has to assume something.  Documentation for p.adjust says "Note that you can set n larger than length(p) which means the unobserved p-values are assumed to be greater than all the observed p for "bonferroni" and "holm" methods and equal to 1 for the other methods." So, the adjusted p-value for 0.03449 using p.adjust(0.03449,,method = "BH",n=9) is the same as p.adjust(c(0.03449,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),method = "BH",n=9).